# Is it possible to have the same base url for multiple Post types?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two custom post types,one is Courses and the other is Courses Articles but the permalink structure that is required is something like below

Course Post TYpe

```
/courses/course-title
```

Courses Articles

```
/courses/%course-article-category%/course-article-title
```

As you can see Course Article will have a custom taxonomy which will be called 'Course Article Category'

I tried setting the Course Article url to

```
courses/%course-article-category%
```

And set the url for Courses to

```
courses
```

This sample Course worked

```
/courses/course-title
```

But this Sample Article under COurse Article post type returns 404

```
/courses/%course-article-category%/course-article-title
```

I wonder if this is even possible because obviously course article when  view in the front end wordpress will hunt for a post under courses but it's meant for Course Article.

Comment: Yes I think that is possible like this `https://yourwebsite.com/article/?id=HERE-THE DIFFERENT-POST-ID`

Comment: the requirement is both custom post types are going to have /courses/ as their base

Comment: Then `https://yourwebsite.com/courses/%course-article-category%/?id=course-article-title`